# Get a value based on another column's value

Tags: sql, oracle, impala

It's a pretty basic sql statement I imagine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do.

So I have a table where I have three columns : Amount of car sold (AOCS), Day of the week (DOTW), Previous day of the week (PDOTW).

I'd like to have the amount of car sold for the previous day in a fourth column. For example, let's say I have sold 4 cars on Monday, 5 cars on Tuesday, 3 cars on Wednesday.

On the Tuesday line, I'd like to have '4' written, as it is the amount of cars sold on Monday.

I'm not sure if I make sense, let me know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to join your table on itself

```
SELECT A.DOTW, A.AOCS, A.PDOTW, B.AOCS
FROM 
  MY_TABLE A
LEFT JOIN
  MY_TABLE B 
ON
  A.PDOTW=B.DOTW
```

Comment: The left join is to ensure that you don't skip a row if you dont have a row for the previous day.